# php html drop down to mysql

Tags: php, html

Okay ive been experimenting with php and my sql for the last day or so.

But I have been trying to make a simple input form that a user will fill out on a webpage and then it flows into my (mysql) server so far I have it taking the FirstName LastName Gender and City But the next question is state and that propose a bit of a issue I have a drop down with all 50 states but I think my html is missing a factor at witch will allow my php script to grab it

Here is the code for my state drop down

```html
State: <select>
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
<option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
<option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
<option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
<option value="California">California</option>
<option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
<option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
<option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
<option value="Florida">Florida</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
<option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
<option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
<option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
<option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
<option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
<option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
<option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
<option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
<option value="Maine">Maine</option>
<option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
<option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
<option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
<option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
<option value="Montana">Montana</option>
<option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
<option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
<option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
<option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
<option value="New York">New York</option>
<option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
<option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
<option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
<option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
<option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
<option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
<option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
<option value="Texas">Texas</option>
<option value="Utah">Utah</option>
<option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
<option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
<option value="Washington">Washington</option>
<option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
<option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select><br>
```

And here is how I have been optaining the other elements

```
<?php
include"config.php";
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];

$insert = 'INSERT into content(FirstName, LastName, Gender)     VALUES("'.$FirstName.'","'.$LastName.'", "'.$Gender.'")';
mysql_query($insert);
```

Not sure how to do this?

Comment: Firstly, mysql_ functions are in a deprecation process right now, avoid from using them.    
Secondly, you are vulnerable to sql injection attack here.

Comment: I don't know how can you please explain?

Comment: read about http://php.net/PDO or http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your select control a name:

```
<select name="State">
```

And from your php script grab it like:

```
$state = $_POST['State']
```

Answer (score 5):

First off your `<select>` needs a name attribute:

```
<select name="state">
```

Then you need to capture it in your php:

```
$state = $_POST['state'];
```

Then you need to add it to your sql statement

```
$insert = 'INSERT into content(FirstName, LastName, Gender, State)     VALUES("'.$FirstName.'","'.$LastName.'", "'.$Gender.'", "'.$state.'")';
```

This is assuming that you have a column in your `content` table called state and it resides directly after gender.

And as always don't use mysql_* functions. Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Put a name attribute in the  tag:

```
<select name="State"> ...
```

And yes, mysql_ functions are deprecated. Look for mysqli_ ... or better yet, consider using ORM's from mature frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the `<select>` tag an id or a name, Like so:

```
<select id="state" name="state">
```

Then, you obtain it in PHP like this:

```
$state= $_POST['state'];
```

Comment: You need to give it a name attribute not ID so `<select name="state">`

Comment: the id is used exclusively client side, where as he name  is passed server-side.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
State: <select name="State">
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
<option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
<option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
<option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
<option value="California">California</option>
<option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
$State = $_POST['State'];
```

use mysqli or PDO to connect to mysql, not use vulnerable code as above.

Comment: im so confused everyone keeps saying vulnerable code but this is how every tutorial on youtube shows me to build this im so lost on how to protect this I have two days invested in this and now im worried.

Comment: Lol how is learning from youtube a downgrade it has to be one of the most active tutorial communities around

Comment: wow not very friendly makes me think twice about this community to just basically tell people that there methods are useless and shun them is extremely rude and not a way to help the community grow. I thought the point of this site was to help people.

Comment: @bushman yes and i helping you much more than you expecting. The point of this site is help, [not be nice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/). Just think about this - you want learn or watch videos ?

Answer (score 0):

Your states list box needs a name attribute

<`select name="state" value="Alabama">Alabama</select>`

then you may capture the value as this way:

```
$state= $_POST['state'];
```

Then add it in your SQL sentence.

That's it.